# Why is Eclipse resolving org.apache.log4j.Level as java.util.logging.Level?

Tags: eclipse

Can somebody answer me what's going on here below?
[image: org.apache.log4j.Level]

I am using a decompiler plugin, called JD-Core. Is it messing up class resolution? Or what?

Now I can't run my application neither because of this bug. I build my application as a Maven project, and Maven builds the jar file without any problem. I can also run the app from command line.

Any thoughts on this? Please find the Eclipse console stacktrace below:

```
    Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
    Reported exception:
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:129)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:302)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)
        at com.rakuten.gep.sitemap.setup.Configuration.(Configuration.java:21)
        at com.rakuten.gep.sitemap.main.Main.(Main.java:22)
        at com.rakuten.gep.sitemap.main.Main.main(Main.java:29)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 8 more
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:129)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:302)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)
        at com.rakuten.gep.sitemap.setup.Configuration.(Configuration.java:21)
        at com.rakuten.gep.sitemap.main.Main.(Main.java:22)
        at com.rakuten.gep.sitemap.main.Main.main(Main.java:29)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 8 more
```

---

[EDIT]

OK, following this link I could solve my problem:

[Deleting the workspace solves the strange error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233656/strange-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-in-eclipse)

The third comment in the answer of @rmtheis suggests deleting the whole workspace. I stil don't know why is this needed, and how does it solve the issue, but now everything works fine.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level` means the class is not on your `Java Build Path`. That it's showing you something else is kind of irrelevant. What you think it *should* be showing you can't be found. That you're seeing this problem at *runtime* says that your Maven setup is not building it right.

Comment: @nitind Thanks for the answer. I don't quite understand what you're saying. I am using m2e. How can I check if m2e is building my Maven project right or not? Can you help me on that? My pom.xml contains log4j as a dependency. As I told in the comment the app works well in the command line.

Comment: The `NoClassDefFoundError` is not happening when you run your application? When does it happen? Have you tried right-clicking on the project and telling it to update the Maven dependencies?

Comment: @nitind Yes, the error happens when I run my application in Eclipse (as a Java application). That's why I don't understand. The project builds without any problem and Maven dependencies are added to the classpath in the run configuration. Also I can run the app from command line, but not from Eclipse. Yup, I tried it and it does not help (Anyway why should I do this? The maven dependencies are all resolved well and build succeeds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this link I could solve my problem:

[Deleting the workspace solves the strange error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233656/strange-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-in-eclipse)

The third comment in the answer of @rmtheis suggests deleting the whole workspace. I stil don't know why is this needed, and how does it solve the issue, but now everything works fine.