# Web project doesn't run on server if a dependent project is opened in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm developing a web application with **Eclipse 4.4.2**, **Maven** and **Tomcat v7.0**. The application consists of a

- *AppSuite* (`<packaging>pom</packaging>`)
- *AppModel* (`<packaging>jar</packaging>`, has some auto-generated classes)
- *AppUserInterface* (`<packaging>war</packaging>`, depends on *AppModel*)

*AppUserInterface* and *AppModel* are modules of the *AppSuite*.

The issue I'm currently facing is that if I have all three projects opened in Eclipse and I try to run the *AppUserInterface* on the server, everything gets moved to the tomcat `webapps` folder correctly (`*.class` files of the *AppUserInterface* and all the libs including *`AppModel.jar`*) but tomcat throws an exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/app/model/ClassName
```

But If I close the project *AppModel* in eclipse everything runs fine when I run *AppUserInterface* on the server.

I suspect that eclipse becomes confused If *AppUserInterface* shall work with the local *AppModel*.

Any thoughts to resolve this error, so that I can have all three projects open at the same time and still run *AppUserInterface*?

---

**EDIT:** The `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/app/model/ClassName` class is not an auto-generated class.

Comment: What environment are U working on? Windows? Because moving a dir won't work on Windows if some process like your IDE has a file lock on it.

Comment: Windows, I have already checked that all files are copied into the `webapps` folder, and the `AppModel.jar` also contains all needed `*.class` files.

Comment: How auto-generated classes are created?

Comment: Via a maven plugin `pojobuilder-3.4.0` in the `generate-sources` phase of Maven.`AppModel.jar` contains all of these generated classes. What I may have forgotten to mention, the `NoClassDefFoundError` is not one of the generated classes.

Comment: Not all Maven phases are called when run from inside Eclipse. Maybe this helps: http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added the bounty and 2 mins later found the solution ...

The solution is the anwser of *rmtheis* in this topic [Strange "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233656/strange-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-in-eclipse) which I hadn't found until now . A simple `Project->Clean...` solved this issue somehow.