# Decode Base64 encoded ZIP archive (GZIP)

Tags: java, base64, decode, encode

I need to decode a Base64 encoded ZIP archive (GZIP) String in Java.

```
String = "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"
```

Comment: We don't do your job; we try to help if you've tried something and have a problem.

Comment: Hint: decode the string with either DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary() or Base64.getDecoder().decode() (java 8), then use GZIPInputStream with ByteArrayInputStream... You've not said what underlying data is, and that string isn't valid base64 so can't help you any further...

Comment: I'll work based on your Hint. Thanks Adam

Comment: Hey @Adam, What do you mean by the String is not a valid base64 String? Can you please explain me?

Comment: The standard Java Base64 decoding utilities reported an error when I tried to decode it... "Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```java
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.exceptions.Base64DecodingException;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

public class GzipUtil {
    public static void unzip() throws Base64DecodingException {
        String encoded = "PUT BASE 64ENCODED GZIPPED STRING HERE";
        byte[] compressed = Base64.decode(encoded);
        String data = new String(compressed);
        //System.out.println(data);AAAA";

        if ((compressed == null) || (compressed.length == 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot unzip null or empty bytes");
        }
        if (!isZipped(compressed)) {
            System.out.println(compressed);
        }

        try (ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed)) {
            try (GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)) {
                try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader =
                             new InputStreamReader(gzipInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {
                        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            output.append(line);
                            System.out.println(output.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to unzip content", e);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isZipped(final byte[] compressed) {
        return (compressed[0] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC))
                && (compressed[1] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC >> 8));
    }
}
```

Comment: Someone needs to comment on this to appreciate it! Nice code! Worked for me on the first try. Thanks a lot!