# Downloading a ZIP file containing JSON in Groovy

Tags: groovy, zip, gzip, unzip

I'm trying to 1. download a ZIP file in Groovy and 2. unzip the contents of that file.  The code that exists currently is as follows:

```
try{
    URL url = new URL(testUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer "+testPassword);
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");    
    osw.write("");
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
    os.close();  
    

    conn.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String output2;

    StringBuffer response2 = new StringBuffer();
    while ((output2 = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
          response2.append(output2);
          println(output2.toString());
    }

    println("Output:-" + output2.toString()); 
    bufferReader.close();
    // printing result from response
    println("Response:-" + response2.toString()); 

} catch (Exception e) {
    println("Error:"+e.getMessage());
    println("Error:"+e.printStackTrace());
    
}
```

(variables are defined earlier in the code.)

When I run this on a valid URL containing a ZIP file, I get the following output:

```
Response:-P�;Uv�4J  -p��A���5�� ���K\G�"�)�荚���%nM%��Qf��Z�$���m����PK�;Uv��4J  -payload.jsonPK[UJ
```

I can tell from reading the response that it's reading in the file somewhat-correctly, hence the `Payload...json` string in the content, but what I don't understand is how to convert that response (which looks like base64 to me) into a usable/human-readable string.  I've tried a number of solutions found in other answers - for example, putting this following function in the code:

```
def unzip(String compressed){
    def inflaterStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed.decodeBase64()))
    def uncompressedStr = inflaterStream.getText('UTF-8')
    return uncompressedStr
}
```

and then calling it via `unzip(theLargeResponse)`.  When I try that, I get `Error:bad character in base64 value` error - but I can't determine where the bad character is coming in or how to mitigate it.  I've also tried the answer suggested here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45854656/5266746

But that gives me compilation errors when I put the string above in the `PUT BASE 64ENCODED GZIPPED STRING HERE` spot. I'm wondering if I'm even going about this the right way.  Does anyone see anything that might stick out or make this make a bit more sense to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

zip is not gzip. gzip is not zip.

You are reading in a zip file, indicated by the first two bytes "PK". You are then trying to decode it as a gzip file, which it isn't. You need save the thing and unzip it with unzip.